Higher Lemmas and Topics for the International Mathematics Olympiad
I am passionate about mathematics and want to reach IMO camp this year. I have learnt a lot of theorems and lemmas and have learned enough to clear the first 2 levels of IMO in my country.( I have cleared them twice). But I have been unable to crack the third level. I want to learn more advanced topics to crack the level but I don't know how to start with them.
Can you recommend the topics and possibly some books?
(Also there are very less people teaching these advanced topics in my country)

I dream the day that somebody will solve IMO questions of the form "Calculate the last $m$ digits of $n^{n^{n^{\ldots}}}$" ($n, m \in \mathbb{N}$) by invoking our Equation (16) of [ https://nntdm.net/volume-28-2022/number-3/441-457/ ]. I've done it this way on a little Italian forum that shares some problems from old national math competitions.

Just to give you a little example of the power of this formula: you can easily prove that the rightmost digit of Graham's number (i.e., $G_{64}$) that differs from the corresponding digit of the string generated by $3^{3^{3^{3^{\ldots}}}}$ is (exactly) the Slog_3($G_{64}$)-th, where "Slog()" indicates the super-logarithm of the argument (and furthermore, we can state that the difference between those two digits is congruent to $6 \pmod {10}$).

Please state the country you are from. That has significant context to this question. EG Does your country consistently produce gold medalists? any medalists? field a full team of 6? $\quad$ Also clarify what you mean by the third level, and how many levels there are. EG In the US, are you looking at Math Counter / AMC / AIME / USAMO / etc? How do we know what constitutes a level?

Depending on what country you are in, there are different topics math olympiads may focus on. Particular ones you can focus on are game theory, functional equations, and ineqaulities. These books are my top picks for advanced math contests:
Euclidean Geometry in Mathematical Olympiads by Evan Chen (EGMO): Covers most geometry topics that will come up in any math contest.
Problem Solving Strategies by Authur Engel: Focuses on many topics, mainly focuses on solving problems.
However, the best way to prepare is simply doing lots of problems. Also, you can prepare most individual subjects by searching online for books.
